# Visual Studio 2013 Freezes on debug

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I had problems with visual studio 2013 which was freezing when try to debug the application, I thought this was due to the fact that i have installed visual studio 2012 after vs 2013. So during the troubleshooting i uninstalled vs 2012 and repaired vs 2013 but no luck.

So therefore i decided finally to install fresh windows 8.1 on a new partition on the same drive, then followed by vs 2013 but here as well no luck.

The problem : As soon as i attach the process (w3wp.exe) and refresh the page and once all symbols loaded. Now i have 5 breakdown points on different projects or files. so when i try to double click on the breakpoint and go to that part of the code, visual studio freeze (not responding) for few seconds sometimes it takes up 10 - 15sec to move to the code.

Also before installing the fresh copy windows 8.1, i have upgraded my PC ram to 32GB (Max supported)

I have done the following on my PC.

- Ran windows memory test and found no errors.
- Ran memtest86 for 15 hours with 3 passes and no errors.

I am not sure what it could be causing the freezing of the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it freeze on any application or just that one application?  No idea why but I've found that on some MS products, they have to be started at least once as an admin user.  After that, they behave themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its on any application. I always start the vs 2013 as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened after I installed **Desktop Earth**. 
I've also read that installing **Google Earth** can cause the same issue.